# Yeoman: How to install dependencies sequentially

Tags: generator, yeoman

In my generator I want to run `npm i` and `jspm i` sequentially so that the log output won't mixed together. How do I do that?

Currently, if I put them together:

```
install: function() {
    this.npmInstall();
    this.spawnCommand('jspm', ['install']);
}
```

or

```
install: {
    npm: function() { this.npmInstall(); },
    jspm: function() { this.spawnCommand('jspm', ['install']); }
}
```

the will be run at the same time.

I'm aware that I **can** put `jspm i` in the `end` queue, but I want to use it for post-install code and it has the same problem (i.e. all codes in `end` queue are run in parallel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeoman is only Node.js and JavaScript. You'll handle this in the same way you'd handle any asynchronous action.

In Yeoman, you use `this.async()` to define an asynchronous task:

```
install: {
    npm: function() {
        this.npmInstall();
    },
    jspm: function() {
        this.spawnCommand('jspm', ['install']).on('close', this.async());
    }
}
```

Note you can also use `this.spawnCommandSync`